# Issue with installing mod_wsgi on a CentOS 5

Tags: python, apache, python-3.x, mod-wsgi

i have to install the mod_wsgi library on a CentOS 64bits and python3.2, but now is giving me this mistake when i try to run the 'make' command, anyone could help me, thanks in advance!

```
/usr/sbin/apxs -c -I/usr/local/include/python3.2m -DNDEBUG   mod_wsgi.c -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib/python3.2/config  -lpython3.2 -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm
/usr/lib64/apr-1/build/libtool --silent --mode=compile gcc -prefer-pic -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fno-strict-aliasing  -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -pthread -I/usr/include/httpd  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/local/include/python3.2m -DNDEBUG  -c -o mod_wsgi.lo mod_wsgi.c && touch mod_wsgi.slo
mod_wsgi.c: In function 'wsgi_server_group':
mod_wsgi.c:949: warning: unused variable 'value'
mod_wsgi.c: In function 'Log_writelines':
mod_wsgi.c:1732: warning: unused variable 'msg'
mod_wsgi.c: In function 'Adapter_output':
mod_wsgi.c:3010: warning: unused variable 'n'
mod_wsgi.c: In function 'Adapter_environ':
mod_wsgi.c:3589: warning: implicit declaration of function 'PyCObject_FromVoidPtr'
mod_wsgi.c:3589: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
mod_wsgi.c: In function 'Adapter_file_wrapper':
mod_wsgi.c:4024: warning: unused variable 'result'
mod_wsgi.c: In function 'wsgi_python_term':
mod_wsgi.c:5631: warning: unused variable 'tstate'
mod_wsgi.c:5630: warning: unused variable 'interp'
mod_wsgi.c: In function 'wsgi_python_child_init':
mod_wsgi.c:6760: warning: unused variable 'l'
mod_wsgi.c:6658: warning: unused variable 'interp'
mod_wsgi.c: In function 'wsgi_add_import_script':
mod_wsgi.c:7411: warning: unused variable 'error'
mod_wsgi.c: In function 'wsgi_add_handler_script':
mod_wsgi.c:7859: warning: unused variable 'dconfig'
mod_wsgi.c:7858: warning: unused variable 'sconfig'
mod_wsgi.c: In function 'Dispatch_environ':
mod_wsgi.c:8340: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
mod_wsgi.c: In function 'wsgi_hook_handler':
mod_wsgi.c:8905: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
mod_wsgi.c:8907: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
mod_wsgi.c:8909: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
mod_wsgi.c:8913: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
mod_wsgi.c:8933: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
mod_wsgi.c:8935: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
mod_wsgi.c:8938: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
mod_wsgi.c: In function 'wsgi_daemon_worker':
mod_wsgi.c:10227: warning: unused variable 'duration'
mod_wsgi.c:10226: warning: unused variable 'start'
mod_wsgi.c: In function 'wsgi_hook_daemon_handler':
mod_wsgi.c:12423: warning: unused variable 'i'
mod_wsgi.c:12421: warning: unused variable 'elts'
mod_wsgi.c:12420: warning: unused variable 'head'
mod_wsgi.c: In function 'Auth_environ':
mod_wsgi.c:13299: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
mod_wsgi.c: At top level:
mod_wsgi.c:7122: warning: 'wsgi_set_py3k_warning_flag' defined but not used
mod_wsgi.c:7824: warning: 'wsgi_set_user_authoritative' defined but not used
mod_wsgi.c:14338: warning: 'wsgi_hook_check_user_id' defined but not used
/usr/lib64/apr-1/build/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc -o mod_wsgi.la  -rpath /usr/lib64/httpd/modules -module -avoid-version    mod_wsgi.lo -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib/python3.2/config -lpython3.2 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.2
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
.
make: *** [mod_wsgi.la] Error 1
```

Comment: Please show the full `./configure` line you did for `mod_wsgi`. And how you compiled or installed Python 3.2 (yum? self-compile?)

Comment: ./configure --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs --enable-shared --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python3.2, i've compiled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Python 3.2 installation appears to be broken, missing bits or build wrongly. Even if you fix it, that will not help unless you are using mod_wsgi from subversion repository trunk as Python 3.2 cannot be used with the official tarball versions. Based on error messages it even seems you may even be trying to use an older version of mod_wsgi than the latest official tarball as line numbers don't match up where would expect.

Comment: I've tried with that version and give me the same mistake, is the Python but i can't find a rpm version for centos of python, so i tried to compile and doesn't give me any mistake, this is how i compile the python3.2
./configure --enable-shared
make
make install

Comment: Based on the error, neither of /usr/local/lib or /usr/local/lib/python3.2/config contains a libpython3.2 library. What libpython3.2 .so or .a files are in those directories? What are the permissions on them.

Comment: They are not installed. Do you think that's the mistake?

Comment: I did it the mistake was on the location of the libpython3.2, when you compile the python the installer move that to /usr/local/lib as libpython3.2m.so/.a/so.1.0, so the mod_wsgi installation doesn't find them, besides the install process creates a carpet inside the /usr/local/lib/python3.2/ calls 'config-3.2m', that puts all the python libs. I did a copy of that carpet and changed the names delete the 'm' from them and works, thanks again!!

Comment: Now the problem is with an undefined symbol inside the mod_wsgi.so, when i try to start the server:Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 210 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 7 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/python.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so: undefined symbol: PyCObject_FromVoidPtr

Comment: As I said, you can not use mod_wsgi 3.3 with Python 3.2. You need to use mod_wsgi from subversion repository trunk as that is the only version with required code changes for Python 3.2.

Comment: Just be aware that have only done the most basic tests with Python 3.2, so there could still be hidden problems I am not aware of. You are at the bleeding edge in using it, especially since not much web stuff has even been ported to Python 3.X yet.

Comment: With Python 3.X i have to make a lot of things as make a middleware code to handle the data comming from the wsgi, specially with the files, that works very well, but i' am thinking to move back to Python3.1 because i' ve been testing my app on that version and works perfect. Again thanks and thanks for the advice!